# Exception in template helper: Error: Can't use $ on template instance with no DOM

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper, meteor-autoform

Anyone run into this issue using a #with?

// Code in the calling template, Helper here just used to pass parameters a sub template

```
{{#with inputControlCheckboxHelper "middleName" "Middle Name" "" "middleNameDNA" "Address" "Alexander"}}
{{> inputControlCheckbox}}
{{/with}}
```

// Just passing in parameters with this helper

```
Template.registerHelper("inputControlCheckboxHelper",
function (inputName, inputTitle, inputSubTitle, checkboxName, templateName, inputPlaceHolder) {
    return {
        fieldName: inputName,
        title: inputTitle,
        subTitle: inputSubTitle,
        checkbox: checkboxName,
        template: templateName,
        placeHolder: inputPlaceHolder
    };
});
```

// The sub template, this calls another helper

```
<template name="inputControlCheckbox">
{{#with shouldBeDisabled template checkbox}}
  {{> afFieldInput name=../fieldName}}  
{{/with}}

{{> afFieldInput name=checkbox type="boolean-checkbox"}}
</template>
```

// The template to check if the input above should be disabled.

```
Template.registerHelper("shouldBeDisabled", function (formName, checkBoxName) {
    var checkBox = AutoForm.getFieldValue(formName, checkBoxName);

    if (checkBox === true) {
        return {disableMe: true, notApplicable: "N/A"};
    }
    else if (checkBox === false) {
        return {disableMe: false, notApplicable: ""};
    }
    else if (checkBox === "") {
        return {disableMe: false, notApplicable: ""};
    }
});
```

In the Chrome console, the stack trace looks like so:
[image]

If I remove the {{#with shouldBeDisabled template checkbox}} line, I get no exception.  Also, even with the exception, everything renders find and the checkbox works with the input.

I'm using Iron Router 1.0.1, Meteor 1.0, and Autoform 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Autoform 4.0.2 solved the issue.